# WebKit Browsers - Unordered List - Extra Space

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit

I've got an issue I'm having with unordered lists in WebKit Browsers. This code is getting injected into a page that I don't own, so I can't really use a CSS reset, but I can't figure out what's causing my issue.

```
<div class='instruct'>
    <ul>For best results please make sure:
        <li>Your entire face including your eyebrows and chin are visible in the frame</li>
        <li>Your face is well lit but please avoid excessive backlighting</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.instruct {
    display: inline;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding:0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.instruct ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    width: 320px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
   list-style: none;
}
.instruct ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    text-indent: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

The result I'm currently getting in IE/FF is that all of the list items are properly aligned on the far left hand side of the UL content box. However, in Chrome and Safari, there is about 20px worth of space between the left side of the UL content box and each of the LI content boxes.

When inspecting the element in Chrome's developer console, the box highlighting affect is clearly about 20 pixels away from the left hand side of the the UL's left hand side. It's like there's 20 pixels of padding or margin coming from somewhere.

Given that padding and margins for both the UL and the LI are all zero, I can't figure this out.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT:
You can see a screenshot of it here:

[image: http://imgur.com/a/Rh4ka]

[image: http://imgur.com/a/Rh4ka]

Comment: I'm not seeing it here: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/Ynvqb/ (borders added for visual clarity) | Chrome 14/Mac OS.

Comment: Yep, not sure what's causing it. I get the same result as you. I added a screenshot of the issue just you can see I'm not crazy!

Comment: I can only assume something outside your given mockup and styles is causing it, as the unit test doesn't show it. Do you have a live URL of the issue to view?

Comment: Due to the content, I can't provide a link to the live URL :(.

Comment: Is your [HTML valid](http://validator.w3.org/)? And is your [CSS valid](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)?

Answer (score 6):

Sorry... necro-thread.. but it likes to place high on Google searches for the topic.

Your inline-block (or inline) gets an extra 4px of space generated by default on the list item. Go up to the UL tag and add a font-size: 0

Problem solved.

Comment: Happy to help. I realize it's annoying to have to re-declare your font size in the <li> but it cleans the problem right up.

Answer (score 1):

try {-webkit-margin-before:0; -webkit-margin-after: 0; -webkit-margin-start: 0; -webkit-margin-end: 0;  -webkit-padding-start:0}
check out http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/css/html.css if that doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be anything inside the `<ul>` tag other than `<li>` tags.

That goes for the text you have directly inside the `<ul>` tag - that is probably what's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with Chrome for Android.

The fix is to not set `margin:0px;` for the `ul` but rather set `margin-left:0px;` and `margin-top:0px;`.